# undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass when calling bundle exec db operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass
/Users/jdrm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `connection_url_to_hash'
```

When I try to run a bundle exec db operation over any rails project like for example:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

My OS is Mac OS X 10.8.4 and I installed ruby using RVM and already tried with the following versions:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

Also tried with rails 3.13 and 3.14.

I appreciate any advise on this problem.

Comment: Using information below I finally found the issue that was related to an existent DATABASE_URL env variable on my machine pointing to some random db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code from `connection_specification.rb`:

```
      spec = { :adapter  => adapter,
               :username => config.user,
               :password => config.password,
               :port     => config.port,
 =>            :database => config.path.sub(%r{^/},""),
               :host     => config.host }
```

The error is occurring because your adapter doesn't have an entry for the path to the database.  However, if you follow the logic that leads here, this method converts a URI to a configuration object.  Not what you probably intended.

So why is this happening?  Most likely reason is that the proper configuration isn't being found. Check what value you have for RAILS_ENV in your environment (if any), and if a matching configuration exists for this.

Comment: Database.yml looks like this:
`
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
`
So I think I am specifying the path to the db.

Comment: change `database: db/development.sqlite3` to `path: db/development.sqlite3`

Comment: Same error...but as fact it looks like the same error is displayed even if I delete all the content of the database.yml file

Comment: Check which environment are you targeting with `rake db:migrate` - are you sure you are running this against your development environment?